How Can I Restart Service once reaching CPU consumption greater than 10%?
I face windows service interruption without clear error added into log file. This error cause CPU consumption to reach around 25%, which causes service to be running without any action. I need to create batch file, In case CPU consumption of the service reaches 20% or more, perform restart to the service. I'll schedule it to run every minute to check this behavior, until I reach a solution with the developer. I use Windows server 2019.
I'm able to get all the services running with same Initials by the below, but I'm unable to identify the CPU Consumption.
Get-Process *Service Initial Name*


If the CPU utilization was only 25% then the service should have ran normally, running a batch script that runs every minute, will only use more resources which you apparently do not have to spare. A PowerShell script should easily be able to list every process, determine the CPU utilization of each process, identify your process you want to restarts utilization and then conditionally restart it. However, doing that every minute, is best done within the service itself…not a scheduled task.

OP is already working to get the service fixed. The computer in question likely has 4 cores and the service is stuck in an endless loop. // @OP: My recommendation, if at all possible, is to check whether the service responds as expected before restarting it, instead of going for the CPU usage.
